# View GAE sources after Cloud Debugger shutdown

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-debugger

In my company we're used to check the sources of our App Engine services via the Cloud Debugger UI (there were a Source shortcut under each version on App Engine > Versions).
As it will be deprecated very soon, and they already did the move to remove the Source button, I struggle to find a way to easily view the source of our App Engine services.

Is it possible to read sources of an App Engine service from the GCP UI? Do they plan to replace this feature by something else? How do you do?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For now, you can directly navigate to your source code via

https://console.cloud.google.com/debug?project=<project_id>